# How to counter firebolt tower + skull tower + snake tower?

Tags: royal-revolt-2

During my war season, I'm encountered by a base with a straight path with a single small bend at the end.  I have no trouble going through the early stages, but then I die from 3 firebolt towers, a skull tower, and a snake tower.

```
        |  |       F marks a firebolt tower
   _Sn_F|  |       Sk is a skull tower
Sk |  _____| F     Sn is a snake tower
 F |___    |
       |   |
       |   |
```

What is the best way to counter this tower combo?

My loadout at the time:

**Troops:** Froster, Cannon, Arblaster

**Spells:** Shield, Firestorm, Bladestorm

Answer (score 1):

You need at least three things to get you through that:

- resistance to poison and possibly fire, and a high health. Pay attention to your inventory and upgrade things if you can
- lots of troops, and keep your troops ahead of you. Duck forward through them to deliver a spell then get back behind them to heal. Keep spawning more troops as fast as you can
- your spells should be pretty high so that it only takes one or two exposures to get rid of the tower

For example, the firebolt can be busy shooting your lead troop, you can run right up to it and bladestorm it, then duck back while the spell works. Even if your troops do nothing more than draw fire they're helping. If they are actually weakening the tower, so much the better. When the spell is recharged, run forward again.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the enemy defense also happens to have plenty of arblasters and paladins.  So what troop would be best suited for cover?  Knights would probably have too less health...

Answer (score 0):

I guess Swordrain, blizzard and heal/shield. Then mandatory cannon. Either froster and another of your comfy troop. Swordrain for the arblasters. Blizzard to slow down FBT, snake and skull. 2 blizzards of good level will kill the skull. Technically bait your King to the FBTs then the cannons shall do the rest. It's just like the staircase of death.